# Problem with linker/joystick input

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, input

I'm trying to wrap my head around getting user input from a joystick/mouse, which doesn't seem all that complicated, but I've run across this simple showstopper: calling `joyGetNumDevs()` gives me an unresolved external symbol error. I've included the necessary `Windows.h` and `MMSystem.h`, so I don't have any idea what may be causing this problem.

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried linking in winmm.lib?